# Multiple Views and an Application Delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Alright, I'm obviously new to iOS development, so bear with me. Most tutorials that I see floating around the Internet are based on the single view template, but I would like to combine some of them into a tab bar. I have three property lists that I would like to assign to individual tabs and use as drill-down navigation data. I've been told that I can assign dictionary properties to individual tabs from the application didFinishLaunching method, but I do not understand how I can assign them to different tabs.

So here's what I have

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window addSubview:rootViewController.view];

NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocationsData.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.locationsData = tempDict;
[tempDict release];

[self.window addSubview:locNavControl.view];
[window makeKeyandVisible];

NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IndustriesData.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.industryData = tempDict;
[tempDict release];

[self.window addSubview:indNavControl.view];
[window makeKeyandVisible];

return YES;
}
```

The error is on self.window addSubview:locNavControl.view because "request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union". I think I might have that part wrong, because I want it to push that data onto the screen when you press a tab. Warning is on makeKeyandVisible because "window" may not respond.

I think I'm doing it wrong, but I would have no idea. Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only make one view key at any given time! Calling [window makeKeyandVisible] 3 times doesn't work.

**Edit:**

Your window can only have one root view controller. In your case it would probably be a tab bar controller. Then you can create individual controllers for the different tabs and add them to the tab bar controller.

**Edit 2**

In general you could probably do something like this...

in your appdelegate.h file...

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
UIViewController *vc1;
UIViewController *vc2;
//... etc
UIViewController *vcn;
```

Then in your implementation file, appdelegate.m, you should initialize the view controllers, then add them to your tabbarcontroller.

```
//Your tabBarController should be connected to the user interface (XIB file), so no need to allocate it in code

//here you can choose to allocate vc1 through vcn if they are not also set up in the XIB
//I recommend doing setup like loading from plist files in each view controller's viewDidLoad method

//If you didn't add the viewcontrollers in the XIB you could do something like this...

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, ..., vcn, nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is just a quick guideline which I hope cleared up a few things! I recommend looking closely at the documentation and going through some of Apple's sample code and tutorials. they're very helpful!

Comment: Then what should I replace it with?

Comment: You should really re-examine the documentation. Maybe start from a TabBarController template in XCode, and look up a nice tabbarcontroller tutorial online. I can't really tell you what you should replace it with since I'm not sure what it is exactly that you're trying to accomplish. I added a small note about the key window to my answer..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Just a few more questions - how would you go through this and assign properties to each individual tab in the application didFinishLaunching method and how do I get the code to connect? Do I simply go into my mainwindow.xib and connect the app delegate to each tab?

Comment: You could that. You can also do it by accessing tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers, an array containing all viewcontrollers in the tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could benefit from using a UITabBarController to achieve the tab-based navigation you mention. Read [Apple's UITabBarController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.